# Howto create an Apache Rewrite rule to redirect Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, user-agent, microsoft-edge

How do you create a simple Apache ReWrite rule for mod_rewrite that will simply redirect any Microsoft Edge browser to a page one fixed page.  This is needed on an instance of Apache that runs on an Intranet and runs one specific application that does NOT cater to Edge, only IE.  When a user tries to go to the application with Edge, this rule should redirect them to a very specific URL on that server that will enlighten them to how to fine IE.

I am facing two issues:

1. I know the rule needs to act on the User-Agent, but I don't know what makes the Edge browser unique from all the others.  Any thoughts on where the best place might be to go and figure this out?  I have looked at Microsoft's web site and they share with you what the strings are, but it doesn't spell out how exactly to tell them apart.  I am thinking that it might be best to look at some open source library that has already figured it out.
2. How I do write a rule for any URL that hits the site EXCEPT the 'enlightenment' page?

Answer (score 1):

In general, User agents are really crappy to deal with. It is best to not rethink it and use a heavily tested library. One of the best is [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser/). It is a collection of regexes to match user agents, with flavors in most languages.

If you want to have this in the Apache logic itself, [you can extract from their list of regex](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-core/blob/master/regexes.yaml#L373-L374)

`(Edge)(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?`

[image]

> How I do write a rule for any URL that hits the site EXCEPT the 'enlightenment' page?

[`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) is what you want to look at